# Canvas fullscreen on mobile devices causes power down

Tags: javascript, canvas, fullscreen, power-saving

How can i make a Canvas Element fullscreen and bypass the power saving feature of the mobile device. My canvas is playing a video but the mobile phone go's into power saving mode after a few seconds. Is there some setting somewhere?

this is my fullscreen function

```
let openFullscreen = (elem) => {

if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
}
```

}

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Wake_Lock_API

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason why this could be happening is because the video is muted